# Timing constraints for DDR output multiplexer

Tags: cadence, timing-analysis, ddr, constraints

Consider the following circuit, which multiplexes the `d0` and `d1` inputs to the `y` output in one clock cycle (i.e., double data rate, DDR).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0sJg3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Which may be the result of synthesizing the following Verilog code:

```
module ddr_mux (
    input wire clk,
    input wire d0, d1,
    output wire y
);

reg q0, q1;

always @(posedge clk) q0 <= d0;
always @(negedge clk) q1 <= d1;

assign y = clk ? q1 : q0;

endmodule
```

I have the following timing requirements:

- `q0` must not change while the `MUX` select input is at `0`
- `q1` must not change while the `MUX` select input is at `1`

In other words,

- `y` must have at most two transitions per clock period.

If the synthesis and timing analysis tools do not know these requirements on the `y` output, they have the freedom to implement the circuit with an arbitrary timing relationship between `q0`, `q1`, and `sel`. Here is an example of how this could go wrong:

[image: DDR Mux counterexample]

And here is the desired behaviour:

[image: DDR Mux desired behaviour]

How do I correctly express this in the form of SDC constraints to be read by Cadence synthesis and timing analysis tools?

Comment: I'm not familiar with verilog, so I'm not posting this as an answer...However, I'm working on a frame-timing circuit where I solved the same problem using ans AND gate + SR flip-flop on each Q input line. Use d0 AND CLK for Set on q0 & d1 AND NOT CLK for Set on q1; then use NOT CLK Reset q0 & CLK Reset q1

Comment: Thanks for your input. But isn't what you describe just accomplished by using D flip-flops as shown in my drawing?

Comment: If your D-flipflops (sorry, didn't catch the DFF labels) are latching based on CLK state, then where is your problem/question? I assumed, based on your statement of needing to ensure no more than 2 Y transitions/clk that you were seeing a failure there.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB: I've updated the question to illustrate what the problem is.

Comment: Ok, looking at your added information, I think you're trying to describe a problem due to mis-matched propagation delays between your DFFs and your MUX selector. In practice, so long as the mis-match is small enough, it is often negated by output/load parasitics. If you're 'seeing' a problem with it in your (actual) output, you may need to add (a) buffer gate(s) to the circuit to delay whichever component(s) is(are) 'getting ahead.'

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB: Exactly. And I want to specify the rules which make the mismatch illegal.

Comment: sorry, I wish I could help more, but I'm unfamiliar with the software tool you are using :(